# Borel mapping, simple functions and step functions

Tags: measure-theory

Say in $R$, I know that every step function is a Borel mapping, but is it true that every simple function is a Borel mapping as well?

I think my question basically reduces to the existence of a non Borel set in $R^1$, but I cannot come up with it myself.

------------------added------------------

My definition of simple function from $R$ into $R$ is a function $f$ which takes on finite number of values

Comment: What is your definition of simple function? I'm familiar with them being defined as functions $\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ whose range is finite such that the preimage of each point in the range is (Borel) measurable. If so, then certainly those functions are measurable.

Comment: Let me add my definition of simple function to the question

Comment: With the addition it still depends. We need more information about what you mean by measurable set. Certainly there are non-Borel sets in $\mathbf{R}$ (a very non constructive proof is this: There are only continuum many Borel subsets in $\mathbf{R}$--how many _subsets_ of $\mathbf{R}$ are there?) If you pick a non-Borel measurable set $B\subset \mathbf{R}$ then $1_B$ is simple (given that $B$ lies inside your $\sigma$-algebra--for instance there are sets which are Lebesgue but not Borel measurable) but not Borel measurable.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear, but I just editted my definition of simple functions. I do not say anything about measurability in my definition of a simple function

Comment: The indicator function of a non measurable set is not an admissible simple function.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of a simple function is one which is a finite sum of indicators of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

An obvious example of when a simple function is not a Borel mapping is simply the indicator of any non-Borel set. An example of a non-Borel set is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets).

However, most people would define a simple function as a finite sum of scaled indicator functions of measurable sets in which case it is a Borel mapping (write the simple function as a finite sum of scaled indicators of disjoint sets, and then the inverse mapping of an interval would be the union of the sets whose scaled indicators lie in that interval).